# Embedding a youtube video on page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm trying to embed a video on my page via a javascript property :

```
value: "<iframe title='YouTube video player' type=\"text/html\" width='640' height='390 src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/W-Q7RMpINVo'frameborder='0' allowFullScreen></iframe>"
```

But when I display this value within the browser the text is displayed instead of the youtube video :

[image]

Comment: How do you add this property/value to the HTML document?

Comment: Need to see more of your code..looks like you're missing a script tag or something of the sort..

Comment: I cant help but wonder why you're doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two options that are shared here:

- use `document.write`:

  ```
  var obj = {"video": {
    "value": "<iframe title='YouTube video player' type=\"text/html\" width='640' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/W-Q7RMpINVo' frameborder='0' allowFullScreen></iframe>"
  }}
  document.write(obj.video.value);
  ```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vb3Z2/)</kbd>

- Use Div and append html using jQuery:

  ```
  var obj = {"video": {
  "value": "<iframe title='YouTube video player' type=\"text/html\" width='640'  
  height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/W-Q7RMpINVo' frameborder='0' 
   allowFullScreen></iframe>"
  }}

  $("#test").html(obj.video.value);


  <div id="test"></div>
  ```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xcL2c/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<script>
    document.write("<iframe title='YouTube video player' type=\"text/html\" width='640' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/W-Q7RMpINVo'frameborder='0' allowFullScreen></iframe>";
</script>
```

Btw.: You missed a `'` caracter after the `height='390`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `div` tag with `id` say `panel`.

Then append this value using jquery like this: `$('div#panel').html('[obj.value]');`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific part of the page, you can add via id or class... id being the simplest... e.g. to insert in a div with id of header:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = "<iframe title='YouTube video player'   type=\'text/html\' width='640' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/W-Q7RMpINVo' frameborder='0' allowFullScreen></iframe>"
</script>
```